# Android Check Internet connection continuously

Tags: android, android-activity, android-broadcastreceiver

I want to check internet connection continuously on every activity with the broadcastreceiver. I already write the code and it perfectly working. But I want to use it in every activity. How can I modify this code?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



private static final String LOG_TAG = "CheckNetworkStatus";
 private NetworkChangeReceiver receiver;
 private boolean isConnected = false;
 private TextView networkStatus;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
  receiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
  registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

  networkStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.networkStatus);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onDestory");
  super.onDestroy();

  unregisterReceiver(receiver);

 }


 public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

   Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Receieved notification about network status");
   isNetworkAvailable(context);

  }


  private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
   ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) 
     context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   if (connectivity != null) {
    NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null) {
     for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
       if(!isConnected){
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Now you are connected to Internet!");
        networkStatus.setText("Now you are connected to Internet!");
        isConnected = true;
        //do your processing here ---
        //if you need to post any data to the server or get status
        //update from the server
       }
       return true;
      }
     }
    }
   }
   Log.v(LOG_TAG, "You are not connected to Internet!");
   networkStatus.setText("You are not connected to Internet!");
   isConnected = false;
   return false;
  }
 }


}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "continuously"?

Comment: Like Facebook, which checks internet connection simultaneously. When I disconnect the wifi/mobile it will show a message in snackbar ("Disconnect") Something like that.

Comment: This doesn't check constantly. It gets an event when something changes and responds to that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to use it in every activity. How can I modify this code?

Create a `BaseActivity` class which extends `AppCompatActivity`, and then make all of your `Activity` classes extend this BaseActivity class. Put your code to check internet connection in the `BaseActivity` class. cheers :)

Comment: I want to check the internet connection continuously on every opened activity. I don't think so this won't help.

Comment: @JewelMahmudNimulShamim the thing is you need to put the code you are using to check connectivity inside BaseActivity so every activity that extends BaseActivity will have that code. this is a very good way to solve your problem

Comment: Could you please give me a demo.I tried 5times dont know where i made mistake.

Comment: you already have the working code, so what's the problem? just move those code into base class, here BaseActivity, and make all Activity classes extend that BaseActivity class.

Comment: Toast only shows when activity started/ OnCreated (if internet connection is not available) but not in b/w while perform any task on specific activity which is extend from base activity

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a BaseActivity without a layout which extends to AppCompatActivity or Activity.
2. Extend all the other activities (or the one where you need to check for internet connectivity) of your app to the BaseActivity.
3. Now use a broadcast receiver in the BaseActivity which constantly checks for network and connectivity state.
4. Reference code for BaseActivity. (In my case, I show a snackbar when there is no connection detected.)

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final int WIFI_ENABLE_REQUEST = 0x1006;

private BroadcastReceiver mNetworkDetectReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        checkInternetConnection();
    }
};
private AlertDialog mInternetDialog;
private boolean isConnected;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    isConnected = false;
    registerReceiver(mNetworkDetectReceiver, new IntentFilter(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    unregisterReceiver(mNetworkDetectReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void checkInternetConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();


    if (ni != null && ni.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        isConnected =true;
        showNoConnectionSnackBar("Connected", isConnected, 1500);

    } else {
        isConnected= false;
        showNoConnectionSnackBar("No active Internet connection found.", isConnected,6000);
    }
}

private  void showNoConnectionSnackBar(String message, boolean isConnected, int duration) {
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
            message, duration);
    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
    TextView textView = (TextView) sbView
            .findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.white));

    if (isConnected){
        sbView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

    }else{
        sbView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.google_button_color));
        snackbar.setAction("Turn On", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent internetOptionsIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
                startActivityForResult(internetOptionsIntent, WIFI_ENABLE_REQUEST);
            }
        });
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
    }

    snackbar.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == WIFI_ENABLE_REQUEST) {

    } else {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create a service. start the service in the launcher activity and put the network check code in that service.

public class NetworkServiceextends Service {

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    //register receiver here
    // connection check code 
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // unregister receiver

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can put your BroadcastReceiver in it's own class, and then declare/register it in your Manifest. That way it will share the lifetime of your application.

An additional benefit is that you dont have to worry about unregistering it, so you won't have to worry about memory leaks.

Comment: This does not work if your app targets Android 7 (API 24) or higher. The only reliable way to get these events if you target API >= 24 is to register the receiver programatically.

Comment: Can you please explain why? Or provide some sources?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION Starting with Android 7, CONNECTIVITY_ACTION is no longer delivered to receivers that have manifest entries. This is because all applications were registering for this event and it was too expensive to notify all applications when the connectivity changed. Starting with API 24 Android only notifies running apps that have explicitly registered a receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Add the JitPack repository to your build file Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
      repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
      }
    }
```

Step 2. Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
            implementation 'com.github.SumonHub:EagleEye:1.0.0'
    }
```

If you do not override the Application class, edit your manifest file to set android:name in the tag as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="org.sumon.eagleeye.EagleEyeApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you do override the Application class, change it to extend EagleEyeApplication (if possible) as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends EagleEyeApplication { ... }
```

In youre activity/fragment get status like below

```
EagleEyeObserver.setConnectivityListener(new OnChangeConnectivityListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(boolean status) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

more info [here](https://github.com/SumonHub/EagleEye)